# Finding Historical Category of Product Based on Sale Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

hopefully someone can help me with the following query.  Basically, I have with the lines of all products sold.  I am using this table to find warranties sold, and the product the warranty was attached to.  Then I am trying to group that by the category of the product it was attached to.

The sales line table has all the warranty, attached product sku, sale datetime, and category of the warranty.  I am trying to join that to a historical category table that has the product sku, the effective datetime of the category, and the category of the product for that effective date.

I am having trouble figuring out how exactly to do the join so the data that is pulled is the historical category for the datetime of the sale.  The products can change categories multiple times over the time period I am looking at, so there are multiple entries for the same item in the historical table.

Using SQL Server, thanks for any help.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
a.[Invoice Number]
,a.[SKU]  
,a.[Item Category Code]      
,a.[Sale Date]    
,b.[Effective Date]  
,b.[Category Code]   
FROM [Sales Invoice Line] a
LEFT JOIN [Item Category Division History] b ON a.[Warranty Item_Resource No_] = b.[Item No_] 
WHERE [Sales Date] between '2013-10-01' and '2014-09-30' AND b.[Division Code] is not null
```

Comment: Please provide some of the sql you have tried. It will be easier to evaluate your question

Comment: do you need items from the latest or the most historical date in the history table?

Comment: I need the category of the item that the item was set to at the sales time.  I think what I need to do is have a where statement on the historical table for the date range I am looking at and then have it pull just the most recent effective date that is < the sales date.

Comment: Does [Item Category Division History] have a PK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t fully understand your tables and how they relate to each other. But I think the following will give you the idea.

Suppose you have 2 tables Sales and History as follows;

Sales Table

```
Date | Item | Invoice_number
```

History Table

```
Date | Item | Category
```

and you want a report as;

```
Invoice_number | Item | Category
```

where category is the category effective for the item as of the sales date, you can use the following;

```
Select s.invoice_number, s.Item, h.category
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN history h
ON s.item = h.item
INNER JOIN (
    Select MAX(h.date) date, s.invoice_number, s.item
    From sales s
    Inner Join history h
    ON s.item = h.item AND h.date <= s.date
    Group By s.invoice_number, s.item
)a on a.date = h.date AND a.item = s.itme AND a.invoice_number = s.invoice_number
```

The inner query looks for the `date` on which the `category` was last changed for `item` before every sale. It is then used as an `Inner Join` to filter the outer query which includes `category`.

We cannot include category in the inner query, because it would require to also group by category and it would return a record for each category to which the item was assigned before the sales date.